# Actual database size of sql server database

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

Currently, i am using SQL server 2012, I have to show database size before user backup database file.So I run the query

```
sp_helpdb 'MyDB'
```

It shows me `db_size` is 1444.93 MB but when I backup database file, It actual size is 70 MB. Why database size so different? please let me known which one is the actual size of the database.

Answer (score 1):

You have backup compression turned on the instance which would account for the size differences.  Also database file may have empty space which is not backed up.

Answer (score 0):

***To Check Database Size in SQL Server for both Azure and On-Premises-***

**Method 1 – Using ‘sys.database_files’ System View**

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME() AS [database_name],
    CONCAT(CAST(SUM(
        CAST( (size * 8.0/1024) AS DECIMAL(15,2) )
    ) AS VARCHAR(20)),' MB') AS [database_size]
FROM sys.database_files;
```

**Method 2 – Using ‘sp_spaceused’ System Stored Procedure**

```
EXEC sp_spaceused ;
```